# ¿Cómo resolver el problema XOR con percepton simple?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando resolver el problema XOR para un percepton simple. El problema es que no encuentro ningun codigo base por el cualguiarme.
Alguien sabe o ha resuelto este tipo de problema o tiene algun codigo de guia?
Gracias de antemano
He tratado la siguiente formula

```
libray (neuralnet)
input1=c(1,1,0,0)
input2=c(1,0,1,0)
outputXOR=c(0,1,1,0)
datos1=cbind(input1,input2,outputXOR)
matriz<-matriz(nrow=4, ncol=100)
for(i in 1:100){
set.seed(i)
modelo<-neuralnet(ouputXOR~input1+input2,data=datos1)
matriz[,i]=as.vector(predition(modelo)$rep[,3])
}
```

Esto resuelve el problema????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver el problema del XOR necesitarás un modelo tipo [perceprton multicapa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptr%C3%B3n_multicapa#:%7E:text=El%20perceptr%C3%B3n%20multicapa%20es%20una,(tambi%C3%A9n%20llamado%20perceptr%C3%B3n%20simple).), básicamente tienes dos entradas para los valores de `input1` e `input2` y una capa de salida y la pregunta es cuantas capas ocultas y de cuantas neuronas asignar al problema. Puedes probar distintas configuraciones, pero para este problema funciona bien un modelo con una capa y dos neuronas:

```
library (neuralnet)

df <- data.frame(input1 = c(1,1,0,0),
                 input2 = c(1,0,1,0),
                 outputXOR = c(0,1,1,0))

modelo <- neuralnet(outputXOR ~ input1 + input2, data=df, hidden = c(2))
```

`hidden = c(2)` establece 1 capa con 2 neuronas, para agregar más capas y más neuronas puedes extender este vector, por ej: `hidden = c(3,2,5)` establece 3 capas de 3, 2 y 5 neuronas cada una.

Puedes analizar el modelo gráficamente: `plot(modelo)`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O bien analizar la predicción sobre los datos de "entrenamiento":

```
prediction(modelo)

Data Error: 0;
$rep1
  input1 input2    outputXOR
1      0      0  0.023535016
2      1      0  0.994911863
3      0      1  0.994018955
4      1      1 -0.007439968

$data
  input1 input2 outputXOR
1      0      0         0
2      1      0         1
3      0      1         1
4      1      1         0
```

Claramente este es un problema teórico, con un escenario muy limitado: los datos de entrenamiento ya es el universo de casos posibles, pero si no lo fuera, el modelo de trabajo en R es básicamente siempre el mismo para cualquier tipo de modelo 1) se entrena un modelo 2) Se predice con `predict()`. En este caso haríamos algo así

```
set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(input1=sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                   input2=sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))

test$outputXOR = predict(modelo, newdata = test)
test

   input1 input2    outputXOR
1       0      0  0.023535016
2       1      0  0.994911863
3       0      0  0.023535016
4       0      0  0.023535016
5       1      0  0.994911863
6       0      1  0.994018955
7       0      1  0.994018955
8       0      1  0.994018955
9       1      1 -0.007439968
10      1      0  0.994911863
```

En este ejemplo, con datos sintéticos, usamos el modelo para predecir el valor de `outputXOR` que es un valor continuo que se acerca al 0 o al 1. Podemos aplicar un umbral de corte para que la salida sea adecuada a lo que esperamos:

```
test$outputXOR = ifelse(predict(modelo, newdata = test) > 0.5, 1, 0)
test

   input1 input2 outputXOR
1       0      0         0
2       1      0         1
3       0      0         0
4       0      0         0
5       1      0         1
6       0      1         1
7       0      1         1
8       0      1         1
9       1      1         0
10      1      0         1
```